# Android notification action broadcast security?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android service that shows notifications with actions. These actions have broadcast pending intents set, for example with an action `ABC`.

The service registers its own dynamic `BroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate` with an `IntentFilter` for action `ABC` to be called when the action is pressed.

This works, but doesn't this mean that other apps can also maliciously send that broadcast? How can the service verify that the broadcast came from its own notification, and not elsewhere?

Comment: add: android:exported="false" to <receiver> tag in your manifest

Comment: The receiver is added dynamically in the service, not in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are broadcasting messages from your service, to your service (which it sounds as though you are), check out the `LocalBroadcastManager` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

This is specifically designed to prevent other applications doing malicious things with your broadcasts.